# How do I scan for open ports on a server using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, server, port, ports, scanning

I am trying to write a script which will take in a server name and a port and checks if that port is open. Not sure how to do this is VBS. I've scoured the internet and have found nothing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [Download PortQry Command Line Port Scanner Version 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148)
 from Microsoft.com and extract it..

Then define some variable as below:

```
strPortQry = "C:\PortQryV2\PortQry.exe"
strServer = "127.0.0.1"
intPortNo = 8080
```

And Use the `PortQry` utility to find a port listen or open with this code:

```
PortQry.exe -n 127.0.0.1 -e 80
```

Something like :

```
objShell.Exec(objFSO.GetFile(strPortQry).ShortPath & " -n " & strServer & " -e " &  intPortNo)
```

You can loop on port and chech any port you want. For more information please check [Microsoft help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310099/description-of-the-portqry.exe-command-line-utility) for `PortQry` utility and check [This Site](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26989431/Need-help-with-a-VBS-to-check-if-a-port-is-opened-on-MS-Windows-Server-if-not-opened-then-retart-the-application-service.html) may be helpfull.